# URL Rewrite to allow Periods for Domains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have certain categories on my website which are for websites or domains and would like to be able to display the domains in full such as amazon.com in the urls (domain.com/category/amazon.com)

Currently as I am using Wordpress, all extra characters are converted to hyphens by default. (domain.com/category/amazon-com

How can I create rewrite rules for certain domain extensions (.co.uk, .com, net, etc.) to rewrite these urls so they show with the periods?

My current htacces contains the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a filter for the [sanitize_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) function.  This also shows you where the replacement of the `.` is in the wordpress functions.  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4/wp-includes/formatting.php#L972

Comment: Thanks Nick - I've written a small filter which works, but I'd like to limit it to only the category URLs. At the moment it's allowing filtering for the actual post titles too: `function dashes_to_periods_com( $title ){
 return str_replace( '-com', '.com', $title );
}
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'dashes_to_periods_com' );`

Comment: You may be able to hook into the `create_category` action to to only apply your filter then.  I'm not sure of the logistics of which will be called first, but it's worth a try.